# Tuples in Dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Is it possible in python to add a tuple as a value in a dictionary?
And if it is,how can we add a new value, then? And how can we remove and change it?

Comment: Add a new value to a dictionary?  Add a new value to the tuple in the dictionary?  Which is it?

Answer (score 32):

```
>>> a = {'tuple': (23, 32)}
>>> a
{'tuple': (23, 32)}
>>> a['tuple'] = (42, 24)
>>> a
{'tuple': (42, 24)}
>>> del a['tuple']
>>> a
{}
```

if you meant to use tuples as keys you could do:

```
>>> b = {(23, 32): 'tuple as key'}
>>> b
{(23, 32): 'tuple as key'}
>>> b[23, 32] = 42
>>> b
{(23, 32): 42}
```

Generally speaking there is nothing specific about tuples being in dictionary, they keep behaving as tuples.

Answer (score 8):

Since tuples are *immutable*, you cannot add a value to the tuple. What you *can* do, is construct a new tuple from the current tuple and an extra value. The `+=` operator does this for you, provided the left argument is a variable (or in this case a dictionary value):

```
>>> t = {'k': (1, 2)}
>>> t['k'] += (3,)
>>> t
{'k': (1, 2, 3)}
```

Regardless, if you plan on altering the tuple value, perhaps it's better to store lists? Those are mutable.

**Edit:** Since you [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784973/tuples-in-dicts/1785112#1785112) your question<sup>†</sup>, observe the following:

```
>>> d = {42: ('name', 'date')}
>>> d[42][0] = 'name2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

This happens because, as stated before, tuples are immutable. You cannot change them. If you want to change them, then in fact you'll have to create a new one. Thus:

```
>>> d[42] = ('name2', d[42][2])
>>> d
{42: ('name2', 'date')}
```

*As a side note*, you may want to use [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s. They work just like regular tuples, but allow you to refer to elements within the tuple *by name*:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name date')
>>> t = {42: Person('name', 'date')}
>>> t[42] = Person('name2', t[42].date)
>>> t
{42: Person(name='name2', date='date')}
```

---

<sup>†</sup>: Next time please edit your actual question. **Do not** post an answer containing only further questions. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change a tuple itself. You have to replace it by a different tuple.

When you use a list, you could also add values to it (changing the list itself) without need to replace it:

```
>> a = {'list': (23, 32)}
>> a
{'list': [23, 32]}
>> a['list'].append(99)
>> a
{'list': [23, 32, 99]}
```

In most cases, lists can be used as replacement for tuples (since as much I know they support all tuple functions -- this is duck typing, man!)

Comment: you seem to be missing some parts

Comment: @SilentGhost: don't be shy, tell it to me! BTW: I did not intent to give a full answer, since you already gave some good advice. I only wanted to add information about lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
t1=('name','date')
t2=('x','y')

# "Number" is a String key!
d1={"Number":t1}
# Update the value of "Number"
d1["Number"] = t2

# Use a tuple as key, and another tuple as value
d1[t1] = t2

# Obtain values (getters)

# Can throw a KeyError if "Number" not a key
foo = d1["Number"]

# Does not throw a key error, t1 is the value if "Number" is not in the dict
d1.get("Number", t1)

# t3 now is the same as t1
t3 = d1[ ('name', 'date') ]
```

You updated your question again. Please take a look at [Python dict docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). Python documentation is one of it's strong points! And play with the interpreter (python)on the command line! But let's continue.

1. initially key 0

   d[0] = ('name', datetime.now())
2. id known
   d[1](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) = d[0]
   del d[0]
3. name changed
   tmp = d[1](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)
   d[1](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) = ( newname, tmp[1](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) )

And please consider using a

```
class Person(object):
    personIdCounter = 1
    def __init__(self):
      self.id = Person.personIdCounter
      Person.personIdCounter += 1
      self.name
      self.date
```

then

```
persons = {}
person = Person()
persons[person.id] = person
person.name = "something"

persons[1].name = "something else"
```

That looks better than a tuple and models your data better.

Comment: thank u very much!
But u know...i;m a beginner in python..and 
i dont really "get" your answer! I prefer ,in my first steps in python to do it in the easy way ;(
i feel silly...but....:(

Comment: I figured that out. This is all stuff you can type on the Python command line, for you to play with. The Person class shows you an alternative way, more structured, to solve this kind of problems.